# mvc razor allow users to select there own theme css

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using MVC/Razor/.Net/C# and i would like to allow users to change the theme of the site just like you can change the theme in microsoft windows.

Does anyone know how to, or, can point me in the direction of some good tutorials/examples.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this functionality is achieved with multiple CSS files and has little (or nothing to do with .NET).

You should design your HTML in a semantic way so that by changing the CSS files the entire output is different with each CSS applied.

This link gives a more explanatory intro into the subject -> http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/switch-alternate-css-styles.shtml

After you do that, what you need to do in your application is to store the user preference (of what skin) in a session or something like that and change the CSS file accordingly.

Asp.Net WebForms use to have the Skin/Theme feature, but I think that it was deprecated (it is  not very good) and I also saw an implementation where instead of HTML the developer used XML and XSLT files to render the views (which is also too complicated for my taste).

Comment: With MVC it actually does have something to do with .NET. That is kind of the point.

Comment: What I wanted to make clear is that MVC does not have anything specific to help you apply themes/multiple styles to your application. This problem is technology agnostic and the same approach would work for different languages and platforms.

Comment: Cheers @tucaz will follow the link provided and take on board your feedback.

Comment: I followed the example from thesitewizard and it works just as i need it too, cheer.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very, very broad question with any number of correct approaches.

You could create a base controller that loads the user's selected CSS theme name from a database during each request.  Then you can put that value into the `ViewBag` (or `ViewData`) and reference it in your view:

```
<head>
  @{
    var themeName = ViewBag.ThemeName;
  }
  @if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(themeName)) {
    themeName = "default";
  }
  <link href="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/themes/{0}.css", themeName))" type="text/stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Comment: Cheers @Yuck will try this out.

Comment: i tried this out, but no success, the viewbag changed but the page didn't. Cheers.